How to configure multi-line text in Inkscape?
I am trying to write multi-line text in Inkscape but after a line carriage the text starts at the first line again and essentially writes over the first line.
My text block is:
ABC
DEF


Internet search told me something about whitespace in CSS and some change which was done in SVG 2. I found however not an actual solution on what to change to have multi-line text.
What property do I need to change to have line carriages properly rendered?
Edit:
I set the 'baseline space' to 1.22 and the spacing to 0.0 for everything.

I also added in the CSS file the property white-space with the value pre-wrap. I found this on StackOverflow but it didn't help.
Edit 2:
A work-around is to reset the properties of Inkscape.
[Edit] - [Preferences] - [System] - (Reset Preferences)

Try this:
With the text tool selected, click on the Spacing button in the control bar along the top, and make sure all the fields are set to 0.

Also in the control bar along the top, make sure the baseline spacing is set to something like 1.2


Unfortunately, it's already set to 0.

@Alex_P I've added something else to try

Hi @BillyKerr, I checked your suggestions but to no help. It worked when I reset the preferences. I don't see however anything different compared to the default properties.
Thanks anyway for your help!

I am still planning to upgrade my text processing from old Remington hardware to software. Remington has the same problem. Typing a CR causes the writing position to return to the start of the already written line. I must after typing the CR also push the linefeed lever to start a new line. Maybe you should do the same. In software there very likely is some token which causes a linefeed to happen after you have fed the token which causes the return of the carriage.
Please, tell how it worked, because there can be also others who plan to move from hardware text processing to software.

Hi Bilbo, can you please elaborate what a linefeed lever is?

It's this.  https://i.sstatic.net/BOixu95z.png The photo is of a much finer device than I have. I have heard (but never tested in practice )that modern versions have combined to this lever also the carriage return, which would be handy.

Hi Bilbo, I think there is a misunderstanding. My questions refers to the software Inkscape.

No problem. I'm interested in software, too, Nice to see, that I can offer something useful even before I have started to use it.  I wish you all the best!
